# Google Calendar Colors are Different Than iPhone Calendars - Can I get the colors to match?

Tags: google-calendar, calendar, iphone

I color code my calendars on my laptop - but annoyingly, that formatting doesn't seem to carry over onto my iPhone

Any tips to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I may have a solution, according to Lifehacker

"If you set up your Google Calendar to sync using CalDAV, the calendar colors sync seamlessly between your iOS device and Google Calendar. If you add a calendar or change a calendar color on Gcal, the colors will sync to your device. Just turn off calendar sync on your Exchange account, and enable it via CalDAV."

http://lifehacker.com/5670967/how-to-sync-your-calendar-colors-between-google-calendar-and-ios

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what CalDAV is, but I just went into my browser and changed the color in Google Calendar and it synced that way to my phone. Reference picture.

[image: Google Cal Screenshot]